# Wouldn't an element of a set always spans a ray of the cone of that set?

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

For context, I'm reading the paper [*A linear optimization oracle for zonotrope computation*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.02439.pdf).

In algorithm 1, line 8, I don't understand the testing condition:

For a discrete set $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. 
It is testing condition:  $\forall z \in G$  if $z$ spans a ray of $\operatorname{cone}(G)$.

Isn't it always true for all elements of $G$?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this paper is using "ray" to mean "extreme ray", that is (borrowing a definition from [Fenchel 1951](https://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/Fenchel1951.pdf))

> A ray (x) of a convex cone C is an extreme ray of C if x is not a
> positive linear combination of two linearly independent vectors of C.

It seems clear this is what is meant in your paper, given this statement (part of proposition 2.4):

> The half-line spanned by a point $x$ in $A$ is a ray of the cone spanned
> by $A$ if and only if the line through 0 and $x$ is disjoint from the
> convex hull of $A\setminus\{x\}$.